# discord.py - already an existing command or an alias for no reason repeatedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This is my code

`main.py`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
  if filename.endswith('.py'):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if client.user == message.author:
    return
# The message logging command comes here
  await client.process_commands(message)


client.run("NeverShareTheToken")
```

`./cogs/botinfo.py`

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from json import load as loadjson

class BotGeneralCommands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client: commands.Bot):
        self.client = client

        self.botconfigdata = loadjson(open("config.json", "r"))
        self.bot_inv_link = self.botconfigdata["invite-link"]

    @commands.command(aliases=["invite", "botlink", "invitelink"])
    async def invite(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("```Hey there! Make sure you have me in your server too! Bot Invite link:```" + str(self.bot_inv_link))

def setup(client: commands.Bot):
    client.add_cog(BotGeneralCommands(client))
````

`ERROR I GET, WHEN I RUN THE FILE`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 618, in _load_from_module_spec
    setup(self)
  File "/home/runner/Main-Discord-Bot-of-ZeaCeR5641/cogs/botinfo.py", line 79, in setup
    client.add_cog(BotGeneralCommands(client))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 507, in add_cog
    cog = cog._inject(self)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/cog.py", line 413, in _inject
    raise e
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/cog.py", line 407, in _inject
    bot.add_command(command)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1155, in add_command
    raise CommandRegistrationError(alias, alias_conflict=True)
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The alias invite is already an existing command or alias.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 523, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 678, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 623, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e

discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.botinfo' raised an error: CommandRegistrationError: The alias invite is already an existing command or alias.
```

I literally checked on every other cog for this discord bot and this command (`invite` exists only here...). Why do i keep getting this error?

What i have done:
I commented out that piece of code, started the bot again and it gave me the same error, but the command name being different, I commented the all shown commands for 11 times ( even though they were only defined in one place ). But i keep getting that error!

This bot has over 240 commands and does it have anything to do with issue?

What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord.py takes function names as command names when you use `@commands.command` without the `name` kwarg. So since you have:

```py
@commands.command(aliases=["invite", "botlink", "invitelink"])
async def invite(self, ctx):
```

The `invite` alias is added, and then the discord.py library tries to add `invite` as a command name since it's the name of the function. You can simply remove invite as an alias to fix the problem:

```py
@commands.command(aliases=["botlink", "invitelink"])
async def invite(self, ctx):
```

Comment: ```
@commands.command()
    async def face(self, ctx, gender="any"):
         pass
```

This is one more command, and it also said that this exsists! And this happens for almost every other command

Comment: ok, i changed it and it stopped giving all the issues! Thank you very much!